# What is best place (if any) to ask about the location / existence of an API?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to get data from a business that offers API (JSON result) on some product properties, but not all. As I do not have a technical question about using the API, or getting the other properties, my question is more on finding the best way to get these properties. For this reason I won't ask on Stack Overflow.

Is there a recommended site on Stack Exchange to ask for locations / access point / use of APIs? (Alternatively, URL for a mobile site) Or am I better off asking in other sites outside Stack Exchange?

Comment: Please include your actual question, that way we can answer you better.

Answer (score 7):

If you're *looking for* an API, you can try

- [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/api)
- [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/api)

Recommendations are a tough fit for the Stack Exchange network, so I'd recommend reading [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377) (the advice there applies on more sites than just Software Recommendations).

If you already have an API but are not sure *how* to call it to get the data you want, you're better off asking the publisher of the API. Most of them have a forum or some kind of support via a ticketing system. The chances that somebody here on the network knows the answer to your question are pretty low.

Comment: "Most of them have a forum or some kind of support via a ticketing system." And what if there is no such forum, or I don´t want to or can´t register there? Is there a comunity for such questions?